# Search engine like syntax for java string search

Tags: java, string, search

I would like to search over a string in java using search engine like syntax.

For example:

String: foo baz bar

Search query: "foo bar" OR baz

Result would be TRUE or found because the string 'baz' exist even though it couldn't find exact match of "foo bar"

Other query examples:

(foo OR baz) AND bar

foo -bar

-"foo bar" AND baz

Is there a library in JAVA that already does that and supports 'AND', 'OR', '-' and parentheses syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct search api, instead we can use regular expression to search or matching a string.

> java.util.regex

The below simple example will you to start with regular expression.

> http://www.kodejava.org/examples/276.html
>   http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
>   http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/

Comment: Thanks. I think regex can do basic matched in this case and will not solve my problem of complex queries. I am thinking of writing a cfg and parsing the query into an AST. Any other suggestions?